# Function that takes either a single argument or a tuple treated as multiple arguments

Tags: python

There is a circumstance where I have a get function which returns a tuple of items. I have a set function and I want it to take either a single item, or the resulting tuple as multiple arguments. However if I use `*args` as the parameter of the set function to allow a variable number of results, it won't work as desired in both situations.

```
def get():
    return 0, 1, 2, 3

def set(*numbers):
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        print(numbers[i])

single = 0
multiple = get()
set(single)
set(multiple)
```

`set(single)` works as intended and prints one `0`, `set(multiple)` does not and prints a single `(0, 1, 2, 3)` instead of iterating through the values and printing `0, 1, 2, 3`. What is the most elegant way to address this, without the user having to manually decompose the results from `get` before piping them into `set`?

Comment: It sounds like you just want to unpack the tuple into the argument list: `set(*multiple)`.

Comment: Use `set(*multiple)` and don't name your function `set`, it can be confusing

Comment: That worked, thanks! I missed the fact that * could also be used to unpack a tuple, was only familiar with it as the function parameter.

Comment: Beside the point, but avoid `for i in range(len(x)): x[i]`, instead just do `for e in x: e`. If you need the index, use `enumerate` like `for i, e in enumerate(x): i, e`.

Comment: Since the `set(*multiple)` approach is apparently satisfactory, this is a duplicate.

Comment: Have you considered something like `if len(numbers) == 1 and isinstance(numbers[0], tuple): numbers = numbers[0]`? (in `set`)

Answer (score 1):

Since the get function returns a tuple, you thought set function takes multiple variable and added `*` before its argument numbers. But the get function returns a single value. i.e the tuple `(0, 1, 2, 3)` is a single value. So, the set functions takes only one argument. That is the one argument itself is a tuple. So, it prints the entire tuple. Just remove the `*` before the argument `numbers`, It will work alright for set(get()). But for set(0), it will give error as 0 is not a tuple.
Here Since you know very well that the argument of set() is either integer or tuple, providing a conditional statement in the function set() is more logical.

```
def get():
    return (0, 1, 2, 3)

def set(numbers):
    numbers = [numbers] if isinstance(numbers, int) else numbers
    L = len(numbers)
    for i in range(L):
        print(numbers[i])

single = 0
multiple = get()
set(single)
set(multiple)
```

Comment: That's not a drop-in replacement. `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()`. You'd need to change the other call to something like `set([single])`.

Comment: Yes, Since the questioner knows that argument is going to be either tuple or int, providing a conditional statememt in the function set() seems to be more logical. I've edited my answer now.

Comment: Ah, good point. BTW, you could broaden `int` to [`numbers.Number`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html) if you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

As answered in the comments: `set(*get())` works well.

Comment: But you said *"**without** the user having to manually decompose the results from get before piping them into set"*...

Comment: @Kelly I suppose it depends what they mean by "manually". I took it as something like `a, b, c, d = get(); set(a, b, c, d)`.